# How do I set an inserter filter based on the contents of a storage tank

Tags: factorio

I have a filter inserter that is set to move barrels and sulfur. I want to set up a condition so that if a storage tank of petroleum is below 10k, the inserter only inserts sulfur.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simplest to use two inserters, one of which is in "Enable/disable" circuit connection mode, but you can use a single inserter if you use two combinators to program its filter:

Wire the storage tank to the input of a decider combinator, and the output of the decider combinator to the filter inserter. Also connect a constant combinator to the filter inserter.

[image: Screenshot 1]

The decider combinator's condition should define when you want barrels to be moved ("Crude oil ≥ 10k") and the output should be the barrel item (make sure it is the correct type of full or empty barrel).

The constant combinator outputs the sulfur item (or any other items you want to be moved unconditionally).

The filter inserter then just needs to be set to “Set filters” circuit connection mode. In this screenshot, the filter was set by circuit, not manually:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: The main issue with 2 inserters is the restrictions on layout, that they can't be pointed in the same direction. Is there a good way around that? Regardless, brilliant answer.

Comment: @deworde I assume you mean that *your* layout has room for only one inserter (there's no rule about multiple inserters in general). If so, then no (except for using mods which add things like 90-degree inserters).

Comment: Yes, exactly. The existing layout has a single box as its "source" point, so I can only hook one inserter up to it for each direction.